# Recording microphone and system sound in separate tracks in Audition CC

Tags: adobe-audition

In the past, I've been using Voicemeeter to record my microphone and system audio in separate tracks in Audition. The system audio track is used to sync up the actual recordings of other hosts on a podcast.

However, I found out that Audition and Voicemeeter don't always play nice together, so I wanted to take it out of the equation.

My problem is that I can't figure out how to record my system audio to one track and my own microphone to another. It looks like it would be possible using WASAPI by enabling stereo mix, but that results in very choppy sound.

[here's an example of what I mean](https://i.eliens.co/1524821583667.mp3)

What can I do to solve this issue?

I am running Windows 10 Pro, and using the latest version of Audition CC

Comment: OK...first of all...what is the setup?
USB Mic or XLR and an interface? There are many ways to do it with an interface or mixer...
But I cannot answer without first knowing what you have

Comment: @DarkCornerStudios I'm using a condenser mic that's connected to the mic input on my computer through a phantom power supply